# Business Jargon "Blue Ocean Market"

Tags: terminology

What is the meaning of  the expression "blue ocean market" used in business jargon?

Comment: What search methods did you use on your own?  Can you give us some context?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a market that your company has all to itself. You create the demand rather than competing in an existing market against rivals.

[More information](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Blue_Ocean_Strategy).